# If условие php

Tags: php

Скажите как реализовать если я хочу делать if условие если последнего запроса из бд прошла 60 секунд то показывать из кэша.

Comment: установить TTL в кэше 60 сек., и если нет в кэше — брать из БД

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял автора:
Как реализовать функцию подгрузки данных из кэша, если последнее обращение к базе данных было менее, чем за 60 секунд до настоящего.

---

Время обращения к БД можно писать в сессию(если это делается для отдельного юзера) и в саму БД.

В первом случае пишем:

```
if((time()-$_SESSION['last_query'])<60){//если прошло менее 60 секунд
  show_from_cache();//ваша функця
}else{
  $_SESSION['last_query']=time();
  show_from_db();//другая ваша функция
}
```

во втором случае придется разделять запросы к таблице времени и запросы к остальным таблицам. Самое простое, хоть и не самое правильное:

```
my_query($sql){
  if(strpos('last_query_time_table',$sql)!==false){
    //запрос к таблице времени
  }else{
    //запрос к остальным таблицам
    //Сюда же пишем обновление таблицы времен.
  }
}
```

Затем все запросы вызывайте через эту функцию.